# MySQL: splits row into multiple rows with join table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing table with the following structure

```
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+
| employee_id | val_1 | val_2 | val_3 | ...
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+
|         123 |     A |     B |     C |
```

I want to change this single table into 2 tables - one which contains the values in seperate rows, and another with becomes a join table for this.  For example, the above would be turned into this:

```
+-------------+--------+      +----+-------+
| employee_id | val_id |      | id | value |
+-------------+--------+      +----+-------+
|         123 |      1 |      |  1 |     A |
+-------------+--------+      +----+-------+
|         123 |      2 |      |  2 |     B |
+-------------+--------+      +----+-------+
|         123 |      3 |      |  3 |     C |
+-------------+--------+      +----+-------+
```

What's the best SQL to use to convert the existing table into these 2 new tables?  I can create the values table easy enough, but I'm not sure how to create the join table at the same times.

Comment: Sorry not proficient in MySQL but any answer should factor in that your original table may have a uniqueness constraint on employee_id (eg if it's the primary key) that will cause problems in your new table format... constraint needs to be removed, relaxed/extended (eg composite PK on employee_id and val_id),  or it might just be easier to create a _new_ employee table (it would certainly be advisable to copy rather than replace, for testing of whatever answer is accepted, anyhow).

Comment: You want to run an insert from a select for each column of the original table.  I'd post a full answer but can't be bothered testing for accuracy right now.

Comment: Hi Sepster - The 2 tables are both new, so they shouldn't have to worry about the existing table's constraints?

Comment: Hi mikebabcock, that's what I'm doing to create the new values table, I'm just not sure how to populate the join table as I do this...

Comment: @JohnFarrelly yes you're right, sorry - I misunderstood that you were creating new tables. PS use @ in front of a username to ensure they receive notification that you've addressed them in a comment

Comment: Here's how to retrieve the identity of a column just inserted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897356/php-mysql-insert-row-then-get-id

Comment: Thanks @Sepster, I guess I'm wondering how to do the individual inserts in a loop to be able to use the last id.  I'm doing an INSERT INTO val_table SELECT val_a from existing_table - so the bulk insert doesn't let me insert into the join table as I go (or at least I don't know how to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I ended up writing to do this.  As the procedure name suggests, I was expecting there to be a more straightforward way of doing this!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE iWasHopingItWouldBeSimpler()
BEGIN
   DECLARE loop_done BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;

   DECLARE emp_id BIGINT(20);
   DECLARE val1 DECIMAL(19,2);
   DECLARE val2 DECIMAL(19,2);
   DECLARE val3 DECIMAL(19,2);

   DECLARE emp CURSOR
   FOR
   SELECT employee_id, val1, val2, val3 FROM existing;   

   -- Declare continue handler
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET loop_done=1;

   OPEN emp;

   -- Loop through all rows
   REPEAT
      FETCH emp INTO emp_id, val1, val2, val3;

      INSERT INTO new_values (value) VALUES(val1);
      INSERT INTO new_join (employee_id, values_id) VALUES(emp_id, LAST_INSERT_ID());

      INSERT INTO new_values (value) VALUES(val2);
      INSERT INTO new_join (employee_id, values_id) VALUES(emp_id, LAST_INSERT_ID());

      INSERT INTO new_values (value) VALUES(val3);
      INSERT INTO new_join (employee_id, values_id) VALUES(emp_id, LAST_INSERT_ID());

   -- End of loop
   UNTIL loop_done END REPEAT;

   CLOSE emp;
   SET loop_done=0;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (psuedo-code only, sorry):

```
For each row in (SELECT employee_id, val_1, val_2, val_3 FROM existing_table)
{
   for each val in (row.Values)
   {
     INSERT INTO new_values (val)
     val_id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
     INSERT INTO new_employees (employee_id, val_id);
  }
}
```

There's probably a set-based way of doing this to avoid the loops... but sorry, I don't know what it is as like you, I'm not sure how to get the identity of the values table back into the parent employee table.

And also, while [cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) are generally frowned on, this sort of one-off operation is exactly what they're designed for (ie I wouldn't recommend cursors for regular transaction or report processing, but for a re-structure of data.... why not?).

Comment: Yep, that's what I want to do, I'm just not sure of the MySQL syntax :)  For example, I'm wondering if I have to create a procedure to put the loop in, or can MySQL handle adhoc loop statements?

Comment: @JohnFarrelly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817395/how-can-i-loop-through-all-rows-of-a-table-mysql

Answer (score 0):

for the first result

```
`INSERT INTO new_val
SELECT  emp_id, REPLACE(UPPER(column_name), 'VAL_', '') FROM   
information_schema.COLUMNS ,
employee
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'employee' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myschema' AND column_name LIKE 'VAL_%'`;
```

using first result, populate the query and use it to insert into new table;
May be minor fine tuning required. Not tested

    `SELECT CONCAT('select ', new_val.number, ', VAL_', new_val.number, '
    FROM employee, new_val
    WHERE new_val.emp_id = employee.emp_id and new_val.number = ', val.number, 
    ' union all' ) FROM 
    val ;`

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and bad in formatting. kindly excuse