# Find the date after a gap in date range in sql

Tags: sql, date

I have these date ranges that represent start and end dates of subscription. There are no overlaps in date ranges.

```
Start Date   End Date
1/5/2015 -  1/14/2015
1/15/2015 - 1/20/2015
1/24/2015 - 1/28/2015
1/29/2015 - 2/3/2015
```

I want to identify delays of more than 1 day between any subscription ending and a new one starting. e.g. for the data above, i want the output: `1/24/2015 - 1/28/2015`.

How can I do this using a sql query?

Edit : Also there can be multiple gaps in the subscription date ranges but I want the date range after the latest one.

Comment: Your logic isnt clear.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: I think it's pretty clear. The "gap" is supposed to be more than 1 day between `end date` and `start date` of the very next row.

Comment: No it's not clear. How many gaps can be there potentially?

Comment: it doesn't matter how many gaps, he want's to identify them all. Therefore he needs to iterate through each record and query for `start_date > {{row_end_date + 1 day}}`, then he can deduce his gap. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it directly in sql, I'd have to iterate with an ORM. Most likely you'd need to use a store procedure like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817395/how-can-i-loop-through-all-rows-of-a-table-mysql

Comment: But he says he wants to identify "delays" and then outputs "start date - end date". I give up, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You do this using a `left join` or `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.enddate = dateadd(day, -1, t.startdate)
                 );
```

Note that this will also give you the first record in the sequence . . . which, strictly speaking, matches the conditions.  Here is one solution to that problem:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select min(startdate) as minsd from t) as x
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.enddate = dateadd(day, -1, t.startdate)
                 ) and
      t.startdate <> minsd;
```

You can also approach this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(enddate) over (order by startdate) as prev_enddate,
             min(startdate) over () as min_startdate
      from t
     ) t
where minstartdate <> startdate and
      enddate <> dateadd(day, -1, startdate);
```

Also note that this logic assumes that the time periods do not overlap.  If they do, a clearer problem statement is needed to understand what you are really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using window function `LAG()` that would get value from previous row in ordered set for later comparison in `WHERE` clause. Then, in `WHERE` you just apply your "gapping definition" and discard the first row.

**[SQL FIDDLE - Test it!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53a08/8)**

Sample data:

```
create table dates(start_date date, end_date date);

insert into dates values 
  ('2015-01-05','2015-01-14'),
  ('2015-01-15','2015-01-20'),
  ('2015-01-24','2015-01-28'), -- gap
  ('2015-01-29','2015-02-03'),
  ('2015-02-04','2015-02-07'),
  ('2015-02-09','2015-02-11'); -- gap
```

Query

```
SELECT
  start_date,
  end_date
FROM (
  SELECT
    start_date,
    end_date,
    LAG(end_date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY start_date) AS prev_end_date
  FROM dates
  ) foo
WHERE
  start_date IS DISTINCT FROM ( prev_end_date + 1 ) -- compare current row start_date with previous row end_date + 1 day
  AND prev_end_date IS NOT NULL -- discard first row, which has null value in LAG() calculation
```

I assume that there are no overlaps in your data and that there are unique values for each pair. If that's not the case, you need to clarify this.