# Update a new added column at once in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, updates

I added new columns to the current table  `employee` called `salary`, now I have to add values for 100 records. I don't want to write the update column 100 times,more over I can't define case statement , because salary for each employeeId is different. So the command below is not what I want.

```
     UPDATE employee
    SET salary = 10000
    WHERE employeeId = 1;

THE SAME FOR employeeId = 2,3,....
```

I am interesting to have id as parameter like @id, as employeeId defined **aut_increment** , so in each iteration adding a corresponding values to it.

Imagin salaries are (1000,2000,4000,5000,....)
What are the best way or solutions to do that?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry  I can't undrestand what do u mean by giving negative to my question? and i can't see my answer in the link you have posted here. I am new to mysql and I am asking a question,and 3 hours looking here and not finding a proper answer so if u know something try to help the other rather than rejecting them!

Comment: If you hover over the down arrow, it may offer a clue.

Answer (score 0):

In spring jpa, find all the records, loop through each of the record and do update operation. Example:

```
List<YourEntity> entities= repositoryObject.findAll();

for (Entity e : entities)
{
e.setSalary(<your salary values>). // salary values you can read from a file etc..

repositoryObject.save(e); //Do the save operation on the object you are looping through. Hence other column values still persist in the object. Hence you would update the row.

}
```

Comment: But i need a sql query without using programming.

Comment: Hope this answered question helps! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817395/how-can-i-loop-through-all-rows-of-a-table-mysql