# MySQL fill empty column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have the following table:
MyTable(id, group_column, column_to_fill)

Currently 'column_to_fill' is empty and I want to fill it with increasing integers. The values should start from 0 for every value of group_column.

My table looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+----------------+
|               id                  |group_column| column_to_fill |
+-----------------------------------+------------+----------------+
| 9b71dd5c-d8a6-461c-b1f3-af1e4b1d  | Value1     |     null       |
| 38886977-0f34-4059-b192-f94f5aed  | Value1     |     null       |
| d98e16da-a919-4242-baf8-dbbef636  | Value2     |     null       |
| e1ab88a9-3307-49a6-b37d-72cdb5da  | Value2     |     null       |
| 75174dcb-eb74-4c13-80a1-1b21905d  | Value2     |     null       |
+-----------------------------------+------------+----------------+
```

I want it to look like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+----------------+
|               id                  |group_column| column_to_fill |
+-----------------------------------+------------+----------------+
| 9b71dd5c-d8a6-461c-b1f3-af1e4b1d  | Value1     |     0          |
| 38886977-0f34-4059-b192-f94f5aed  | Value1     |     1          |
| d98e16da-a919-4242-baf8-dbbef636  | Value2     |     0          |
| e1ab88a9-3307-49a6-b37d-72cdb5da  | Value2     |     1          |
| 75174dcb-eb74-4c13-80a1-1b21905d  | Value2     |     2          |
+-----------------------------------+------------+----------------+
```

How can I update it in MySQL?

Comment: you can create a stored procedure, using loop. Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16350693/2469308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend approaching this as:

```
set @rn := -1;
set @g := '';

update t
    set column_to_fill = if(@g = group_column, @rn := @rn + 1,
                            if(@g := group_column, @rn := 0, @rn := 0)
                          )
    order by group_column;
```

When using variables in MySQL, it is *really* important to remember that the order of evaluation of expressions is *not* guaranteed.  So, you need to put all references and assignments of a variable into the same expression.

In MySQL 8+, you can do:

```
update t join
       (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by group_column order by group_column) as seqnum
        from t
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set column_to_fill = seqnum - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect using this simple `SELECT` (further, you can use ut to update your table):

```
select @lag := '', @i := 0;

select group_column, rn from (
  select @lag,
         case when group_column = @lag then @i := @i + 1 else @i := 0 end rn,
         @lag := group_column, group_column
  from tbl
) a
```

`UPDATE` statement:

```
select @lag := '', @i := 0;
update tbl
join (
  select id,
         @lag,
         case when group_column = @lag then @i := @i + 1 else @i := 0 end rn,
         @lag := group_column, group_column
  from tbl
) t on tbl.id = t.id and tbl.group_column = t.group_column
set tbl.column_to_fill = t.rn
```