# MySql - Inserting into the table in a while loop

Tags: mysql

I have a `takes` table, and i want to convert each grade record to the numeric value and store it in the `grade_point` table .

[image]

I initialized the `grade_point` as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS university.grade_point (
    id VARCHAR(5),
    grade VARCHAR(2),
    grade_value NUMERIC(2 , 1)
);
```

I can approach the problem as in the following:

- Get `id` from `takes` table
- Get `grade` from `takes` table
- If `grade` is `A` then `grade_value` is 4.0

  If `grade` is `A-` then `grade_value` is 3.7 ...

I can write the following query:

```sql
insert into grade_point(id, grade, grade_value) 
SELECT 
    id,
    grade,
    CASE
        WHEN grade LIKE 'A' THEN 4.0
        WHEN grade LIKE 'A-' THEN 3.7
        WHEN grade LIKE 'B+' THEN 3.3
        WHEN grade LIKE 'B' THEN 3.0
    END AS grade_value
FROM
    takes;
```

I wonder if I can do that using `procedure`?

Inspired from the accepted solution of [How can I loop through all rows of a table (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817395/how-can-i-loop-through-all-rows-of-a-table-mysql):

- For each `grade` record in the `takes` table

  - Select the `i`th row
  - Get `id`, `grade` and convert `grade` to `grade_value`
  - insert it to the `grade_point`
- Result is:

```sql
delimiter 
create procedure update_grade_point()
begin
declare n int default 0
declare i int default 0
select count(grade) from takes into n    
set i = 0
while i < n do
    insert into grade_point(id, grade, grade_value) 
    select id, grade, 
        case
            when grade like 'A' then 4.0
            when grade like 'A-' then 3.7
            when grade like 'B+' then 3.3
            when grade like 'B' then 3.0
        end as grade_value
    from
        takes
    limit i, 1;
    set i = i + 1
end while
end;
delimiter ;
```

However, the above query responsed as:

> 0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1050 Table 'grade_point' already exists

When drop the `grade_point` table and re-execute the query i have the following response

> 0 row(s) affected

Nothing is inserted into the `grade_point` table.

Could you please tell me what I'm missing or wrong in my `procedure`?

Regards.

Comment: `INSERT tablename (column1, column2, colmn3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)` is proper `INSERT` syntax. You aren't putting in any `VALUES`.

Comment: Why would you want to replace the perfectly fine, sleek, set based and performant `INSERT ... SELECT ...` with a slow and pesky procedural solution?

Comment: On second thought: What's the table `grade_point` supposed to model anyway? The relation between numerical and letter representation of grades? In that case you don't want to fill it according to the rows of `takes` but just one time, one row for every *possible* grade (which must not necessarily currently exists in `takes`). (And afterwards change `takes`so that `grade` is a foreign key pointing to the records in `grade_point`.)

Comment: And yes, *creating* a procedure won't insert or update or delete any rows. You need to *execute* the procedure so that any `INSERT` (or `UPDATE` or `DELETE`) statements in its body have any effect. (Should that have been the question you have. It's all a little hard to decipher what you have and want and what the problem is. At least for me...)

Comment: @stickybit I was trying to visualize the books problem sir. The question was not related with the real-world problem. I'm currently working for a troubled-exam. Thanks for sharing your ideas with me. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, why you want to do this, when a simpe insert is enough

But ij a stored procedure you would use a loop

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  grade_point (
>     id VARCHAR(5),
>     grade VARCHAR(2),
>     grade_value NUMERIC(2 , 1)
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS takes (
>     id VARCHAR(5),
>     grade VARCHAR(2)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO takes VALUES ("1","A"),("2","B"),("3","A"),("4","B")
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE update_grade_point (
>
> )
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
>   DECLARE _grade varchar(2) DEFAULT "";
>   DECLARE _id varchar(5) DEFAULT "";
>
>   -- declare cursor for employee email
>   DEClARE curtakes 
>       CURSOR FOR 
>           SELECT id,grade FROM takes;
>
>   -- declare NOT FOUND handler
>   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
>         FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
>
>   OPEN curtakes;
>
>   getidGrade: LOOP
>       FETCH curtakes INTO _id,_grade;
>       IF finished = 1 THEN 
>           LEAVE getidGrade;
>       END IF;
>                 insert into grade_point(id, grade, grade_value) VALUES (_id,_grade,        case
>             when grade like 'A' then 4.0
>             when grade like 'A-' then 3.7
>             when grade like 'B+' then 3.3
>             when grade like 'B' then 3.0
>         end);
>   END LOOP getidGrade;
>   CLOSE curtakes;
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL update_grade_point()
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM grade_point
> ```
>
> ```
> id | grade | grade_value
> :- | :---- | ----------:
> 1  | A     |         4.0
> 2  | B     |         3.0
> 3  | A     |         4.0
> 4  | B     |         3.0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aaed53768372461669c3dfe6e31e4a92)*

Comment: "I don't know, why you want to do this, when a simpe insert is enough", I'm studying to the qualification exam. Exam community can ask anything. Anyway, thanks. Though I didn't understand why "db<>fiddle" threw an error to my syntax. The query works fine on MySql Workbench.

Comment: dbfiddle, has some querks, that have to be considered see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6315b9a5387232897b1f7a9cf70c470f  , besides try the next time `DELIMITER $$` and add the semicolins, it make for ebtter rad and MySQL while accepting your style get confused in dbfiddle

Comment: I wonder what does "..while accepting your style get confused.." means?

Comment: you have a delimiter without an actual character, this does through dbfiddle in its configuration off. dbfiddle.uk doesn't like the DELIMITER because it  s adds it automaticallly as you can see in the fiddles. like i said, it takes some time to kn owall rules of the fiddle sites

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information, I will be careful next time. Regards